# Big O Notation properties

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

If for functions $f, g$ we have $f = \mathcal{O}(g)$, then does $g = \mathcal{O}(f)?$ Explain why this is true or give an
example showing it is false.

Workings:

I believe this is false. if I take $g = n^3 +20 n +1$ then $f = \mathcal{O}(g) = \mathcal{n^3}$

But $g = \mathcal{n^3} =  n^3 \neq n^3 +20n +1$

Is what I said correct? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stated belief is correct but your example isn't.

You should think of $\mathcal{O}$ as "grows no faster than (asymptotically)". Thus

$$
n^3 + 20n +1 = \mathcal{O}(n^3)
$$
 and
$$
n^3  = \mathcal{O}(n^3+ 20n +1)
$$
and
$$
n   = \mathcal{O}(n^3)
$$
but
$$
n^3   \ne \mathcal{O}(n).
$$

Note: this isn't the formal definition of $\mathcal{O}$ but it is a good way to train your intuition.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks!